Why is the li element height affected due to the line-height property?


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="navbar-links">
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link">Careers</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link">Events</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link">Support</a></li>
</ul>



I mean, line-height property is a very important and useful resource but why does it has to affect an element when it doesn't even has text? (For example: a nav that contains a ul with a couple of li-s inside and this ones anchor tag elements inside)
Probably not the best explanation of a doubt but I hope you understand my confusion.

I think what you're trying to say is if there is not text in li then it should not apply the line-height property.
It is because bootstrap has class defined with line-height property.  If you don't want line-height for li element then you can use another class name for that.
I hope this make some sense.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="navbar-links">
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link lh-1">About</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link lh-1">Careers</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link lh-1">Events</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link lh-1">Products</a></li>
  <li class="li-link"><a href="" class="nav-link lh-1">Support</a></li>
</ul>



